# Alert dialog is gone before the user see anything

Tags: android, timer, listener, android-alertdialog, period

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            
      PopIt("Exit Application", "Are you sure you want to exit?");

        super.onBackPressed();

    }

    public void PopIt( String title, String message ){
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle( title )
            .setMessage( message )
            .setPositiveButton("YES", new OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of YES
                    finish();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("NO", new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    //do stuff onclick of CANCEL
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You touched CANCEL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }).show();
        }
```

***this alert dialog gone so fast as I cant read or click on it !! why is that ?***

Comment: post more code, especially around the call to PopIt

Comment: and you are sure you are not calling super.onBackPressed() ?

Comment: I think you should not call super.onBackPressed();

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you throw the Popit and before you call super.onBackPressed();
delete it :)

Comment: remove the super.onBackPressed(); line

Answer (score 2):

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

remove this line.

if you don't remove it, the default functionality will be triggered which will close the current activity.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub     

 super.onBackPressed();       
      PopIt("Exit Application", "Are you sure you want to exit?");



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Really Exit?")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            youractivity.super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }).create().show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove this line `super.onBackPressed();`

You are displaying dialog in onBackPressed()

so its like your are overriding  behavior of onBackPressed();

so don't call super class method.

Answer (score 1):

remove the `super.onBackPressed();`

this will work :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub          
      PopIt("Exit Application", "Are you sure you want to exit?");
    }
```